# Passing a function to a "button" while an animation is happening via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

How would I go about passing a function to a "button" while an animation is happening *via* jQuery?

JavaScript allows me to select all data under the class of `.nav-items` and the forEach method to iterate through this data and the *nav* tag, to finally pass it on to a class named `.navbar-toggle-show`

The class of `navbar-toggle-show`mainly uses a `display:flex` when the screen is at `max-width:768px`

On the jQuery side is where Im finding my most problems because while I can fadeIn/Out the icons, the function that allows me to toggle the content is not exactly working. What I would like to do is to pass toggle function to the "newly" revealed button.

```js
$("document").ready(()=>{
  $(".svg-nav-toggle").on('click', ()=>{
    $(".svg-nav-toggle").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".svg-nav-toggle-on").fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $(".svg-nav-toggle-on").on('click', ()=>{
    $(".svg-nav-toggle-on").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".svg-nav-toggle").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: #afafaf
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="navbar">      
        <div class="nav-brand">
            <p>Blog Personal</p>
        </div> 

        <div class="svg-nav-toggle hide"> <!-- START OF SVG ICONS -->
                <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="40" viewBox="0 0 10 20">
                    <defs>
                      <style>
                        .cls-1 {
                          opacity: 1;
                        }
                        .cls-2 {
                          fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                        }
                      </style>
                    </defs>
                    <title>Off</title>
                    <g class="cls-1">
                      <path class="cls-2" d="M7.4,1A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,9,2.6V17.4A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,7.4,19H2.6A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,1,17.4V2.6A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,2.6,1H7.4m0-1H2.6A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,0,2.6V17.4A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,2.6,20H7.4A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,10,17.4V2.6A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,7.4,0Z" transform="translate(0)"/>
                    </g>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                
                <div class="svg-nav-toggle-on hide">
                <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="40" viewBox="0 0 16.1 16.1">
                    <title>On</title>
                    <circle cx="8.1" cy="8.1" r="7.6"
                  style="fill: white ;stroke: #fff;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
                  </svg>
                </div> <!-- END OF SVG ICONS -->

       <nav class="nav-items"> <!-- START OF NAVBAR -->
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Acerca</a>
           </div>
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Portafolio</a>
           </div>
           </nav>
        <nav class="nav-items nav-items-right">
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Descargas</a>
           </div>
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
            </div>
        </nav> <!-- END OF NAVBAR -->
        
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function classToggle() {
  const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-items')

  navs.forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('navbar-toggle-show'));
}

document.querySelector('.hide').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question has not received the expected response, probably because there is a lot to read here. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would concentrate on the main points which seem to be the combination of jQuery and Vanilla JS bits. I have two questions: Is there a reason for your `classToggle` function *not* to be written in jQuery? What do you mean by "new" buttons? The buttons are there right from the start. They only change their visibility.

Answer (score 0):

*"Write less, do more"* is still the very true slogan of jquery. In that spirit I took the liberty of rewriting your script and I condensed it into essentially two lines. As I was not sure about the meaning of your on/off class assignation in `classList.toggle('navbar-toggle-show')` I replaced that bit with a simple jquery-`toggle()` function. This is in no way perfect (e. g.: why is the "on" button displayed initially while the navbar is already on?) but maybe it can show you a way to move forward.

I replaced your `$(".svg-nav").on('click',...)` with `$(".svg-nav").click()` as this limits click events to be captured on the `".svg-nav"`-divs only. Otherwise the click-target could have been the div itself, the underlying svg or even the element inside (circle or path). Having the click target "limited" now allows us to use the `.sibling()` function to act on the "other" button. And this makes it possible to get away with a single function for both buttons.

I also put the contents of your `classToggle()` function into the click-event function, as both functions are triggered essentially at the same point. By using jquery I don't have to use all of that `forEach()` stuff as jquery will by default act on all matched elements, so the `.toggle()` method will act on all found `.nav-items`. The argument within the toggle()-function checks, whether the click happened on the "On" button which I identified with the `id="navon"` in the HTML. If so, the element will be made visible, otherwise it will be hidden.

```js
$(()=>{
  $(".svg-nav").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().siblings().fadeIn();
    $(".nav-items").toggle(this.id=="navon");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
background-color: #afafaf
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="navbar">      
        <div class="nav-brand">
            <p>Blog Personal</p>
        </div> 

        <div class="svg-nav" id="navoff"> <!-- START OF SVG ICONS -->
                <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="40" viewBox="0 0 10 20">
                    <defs>
                      <style>
                        .cls-1 {
                          opacity: 1;
                        }
                        .cls-2 {
                          fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                        }
                      </style>
                    </defs>
                    <title>Off</title>
                    <g class="cls-1">
                      <path class="cls-2" d="M7.4,1A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,9,2.6V17.4A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,7.4,19H2.6A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,1,17.4V2.6A1.6,1.6,0,0,1,2.6,1H7.4m0-1H2.6A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,0,2.6V17.4A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,2.6,20H7.4A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,10,17.4V2.6A2.6,2.6,0,0,0,7.4,0Z" transform="translate(0)"/>
                    </g>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                
                <div class="svg-nav" id="navon">
                <svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="40" viewBox="0 0 16.1 16.1">
                    <title>On</title>
                    <circle cx="8.1" cy="8.1" r="7.6"
                  style="fill: white ;stroke: #fff;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
                  </svg>
                </div> <!-- END OF SVG ICONS -->

       <nav class="nav-items"> <!-- START OF NAVBAR -->
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Acerca</a>
           </div>
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Portafolio</a>
           </div>
           </nav>
        <nav class="nav-items nav-items-right">
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Descargas</a>
           </div>
           <div class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
            </div>
        </nav> <!-- END OF NAVBAR -->
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this is working and was the desired function i thought i could do but had to ask for help. Thanks for helping!  cheers.

Comment: Glad to have been helpful here! ;-)